# SQL Insert committed but not found on next request?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, amazon-rds

I have placed an after_commit callback in the RequestToken model that outputs "Committed Request Token xx". You can see in the log I included below, that the token record is committed and the next request the lookup on the object says it cannot be found. The issue occurs intermittently and if I refresh the page the record is found and the request goes through.

**Environment**
AWS EC2 + RDS, Ubuntu 10.04, Rails 3.2.8, MySQL2 0.3.11 gem, apache2 2.2.14, phusion passenger 3.0.11

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions?

```
Committed Request Token S8j311QckvEjnDftNW0e7FPHsavGWTelONcsE3X1
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 21.8ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=S8j311QckvEjnDftNW0e7FPHsavGWTelONcsE3X1" for 96.236.148.63 at 2012-10-15 22:07:32 +0000
Processing by OauthController#authorize as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"S8j311QckvEjnDftNW0e7FPHsavGWTelONcsE3X1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find RequestToken with token = S8j311QckvEjnDftNW0e7FPHsavGWTelONcsE3X1):
```

Answer (score 1):

200 Doesn't mean it saved. Probably failed a validation.

Comment: The record is found on refresh of `/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=S8j311QckvEjnDftNW0e7FPHsavGWTelONcsE3X1` if a validation failed it would not be in the table. Also, "Committed Request token xx" is in the after_commit callback meaning it has been committed. Did you read the question? See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html